# Android TelephonyManager 'answer' event

Tags: android, telephonymanager, phone-state-listener

I've been exploring Android's `Telephony Manager` a bit and fount out there is a way to listen to such events as ringing, off hook and idle. However, it's not enough for me...
When the call is actually initiated, I get an 'offhook' event, but I get nothing when the person I'm calling to, presses the 'Answer' button.

Is there a way to know EXACTLY when somebody actually pressed the Answer button when I call to him/her, in other words I want to know when somebody answers the call?

Any help\suggestions will be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible. There's no such state/event at least I know of. So your best bet would be to stick with **CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK**.